# How to find the specific event executed on the Inspector>Network (web scraping)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, web-scraping

I have been using the following [YOUTUBE TUTORIAL](https://youtu.be/eUYMiztBEdY) to learn how to work with web scraping. I have managed to complete the tutorial with some modifications due to the specific [WEBSITE](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/u) have changed their core structure. The code used for this tutorial can be found in here: https://github.com/beaucarnes/fcc-project-tutorials/blob/master/node-web-scraping/index.js. Now I want to modify this code so that it could work with my objective:

**"Use a search engine from another website [ec.europa.eu](https://ec.europa.eu/eures/eures-searchengine/page/main?lang=en#/search), and try and return the data (i.e. JOB-TITLE) from that page into my NODE console."**

From the YouTube tutorial the event called to retrieve data, was specified from the demonstrator, but didn't actually explain how he was able to use it. In the website i'm seeking to retrieve information, there are 390 events called on that page. I want to identify which `Request-URL` is called for the search engine when submitted. Screenshots are provided below:

[image: DEMO 1]

[image: DEMO 2]

I have search through the events and was trying to find the event called for the search engine. I highlighted in the figure the event name that made more sense to me, but I'm unsure if this is the case.

I also tried to find the event (`Request-URL`) called in the Stack Overflow's search engine, but couldn't find which JS event was called from the Inspector>Networks.

My objective is to identify the specific events called in any website. Any information would be much appriciated, thanks ! :D

---

***UPDATE:***

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const Table = require('cli-table');
const rp = require('request-promise');

const talbe = new Table({
    head: ['Job Title', 'URL']
});


const options = {
    url: 'https://ec.europa.eu/eures/eures-searchengine/page/jv-search/search?lang=en&app=2.4.1-build-2',
    json: true
}

rp(options).then(
    (data) => {
        console.log("DONE");
    }
).catch(
    (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    }
);
```

This will return the following error:

```
StatusCodeError: 500 - undefined
    at new StatusCodeError (C:\Users\loizo\Desktop\eures_test\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\errors.js:32:15)
    at Request.plumbing.callback (C:\Users\loizo\Desktop\eures_test\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\plumbing.js:104:33)        
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (C:\Users\loizo\Desktop\eures_test\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\plumbing.js:46:31)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\loizo\Desktop\eures_test\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, within the network tools you can manipulate the overview to see segments of the requests.
Open up the network tools of the site, make sure you clear all the requests first. Then do a search.

This is far easier in person to show you or a video for that matter. But here's a set of images to guide you to looking at specific parts of the requests made when an action is done on a website.

See the images [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jBGv.jpg). I've explained them individually below

Image1:

- Here I've already loaded the page up you provided and clicked inspect and network tab.
- I'm clicking the button you can see in red to clear all of those requests of the server.

Image2:

- This is what it should look like when you clear the requests

Image3:

- I've done a search for developer and you can see the requests for this action down below.

Image4:

- Now at the overview you can select portions of that action's requests/responses. Here i'm honing in on the first part of that action. You just have to click and drag. Get a feel for this yourself.
- I now can see those 5 requests down below
- The first four requests are GET requests and don't really tell us much
- The fifth request is a POST request this is the one which posts data, the information on the right hand side of the image will tell you where it posts to and what response it gets back.

Image5

- Here is the same image as before but Ive scrolled down abit to see the payload. That is the key things that need to given along with the POST HTTP request to do a search on this website.

### Coding Example

Note the comments on my post. Below is a code example that gets the JSON data you desire.

A collarary, that I Have never coded in node.js, so please be mindful of that! It does however work.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const Table = require('cli-table');
const rp = require('request-promise');

const talbe = new Table({
    head: ['Job Title', 'URL']
});


const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://ec.europa.eu/eures/eures-searchengine/page/jv-search/search?lang=en&app=2.4.1-build-2',
    json: true,
    body: {
        "keywords":[{"keyword":"developer","specificSearchCode":"EVERYWHERE"}],"positionScheduleCodes":[],"positionOfferingCodes":[],"educationLevelCodes":[],"euresFlagCodes":[],"nutsCodes":[],"notSpecifiedInNutsCodes":[],"requiredExperienceCodes":[],"solidarityContextCodes":[],"otherBenefitsCodes":[],"occupationUris":[],"includeJobsWithoutBenefits":false,"requiredLanguages":[],"includeJobsWithoutRequiredLanguages":false,"sortSearch":"BEST_MATCH","resultsPerPage":10,"page":1,"sessionId":"g07h0s8tfmmtfr5u9lible"
    },
    headers: {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'ajax-call': 'true',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Origin': 'https://ec.europa.eu',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
        'Referer': 'https://ec.europa.eu/eures/eures-searchengine/page/main?lang=en',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        }
    
}

rp(options).then(
    (data) => {
        console.log("Got results =", data);
    }
).catch(
    (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    }
);
```

### Explanation

In terms of additions to your own code, I've specifed that we're doing a POST request.

To get the additional things you need to make a successful HTTP Request you can right click the request in network tools, there's a bunch of options but you can copy it to CURL(bash). I used https://curl.trillworks.com/ to convert the curl command. You can select node.js.

I copied the headers as found on that website.

The `body {}` should contain our payload, in this case I copied the datastring on curl.trillworks.

I get the desired output.

### Additional Information

1. Reverse engineering HTTP requests is about mimicing the requests, to make the server belief you're not a bot.
2. You can try just making a request to the server without anything else posting in this case it did not work you get a status code 500 error.
3. You have to think about the headers, any cookies, parameters required to mimic the request.
4. Here you just needed the headers and the parameters (that is the search terms you make when you do a search on this website)
5. Remember its a POST HTTP request you are giving the server information and expecting a response based on that post.

### Additional Links

Request Docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

This was helpful in writing the request for JSON. Didn't fully explain that the body parameter could contain any data we wanted. I took that leap and it worked.

https://beshaimakes.com/js-scrape-data#case-1--using-apis-directly

Useful just for additional scraping plus abit about JSON scraping. Doesn't quite explain the headers part of it but hopefully with this example you can follow along.

https://stackabuse.com/the-node-js-request-module/

Useful in getting my head around the Request library, found this after I made your code work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will jump into it, once I get back home and let you know if that works! :D looks like I will be able to access the search engine by roughly going through the images provided. Thanks again @AaronS

Comment: I have managed to find the information I'm seeking in the Inspector>Network. But the URL from that request doesn't seems to load on NODE as it did with the other example. Code is provided under UPDATE. Also is there any official documentation on how to learn all of these?

Comment: Have you tried putting in the headers you can obtain from the network tools ? Sometimes just making an HTTP request without headers /useragent will not get you the data you want. So within options putting  headers: {
        XXX
    }, You'll need to put the payload in as well, to get the data you want. Remember it's a form you need to in put your search items too.

Comment: https://beshaimakes.com/js-scrape-data#case-1--using-apis-directly - Gives a pretty good write up of inputting headers in. Case 1 in your case, as we're trying to get data from the api.

Comment: I've just updated the answer with code that seemed to work for me. Please check it, I've never coded in node.js before but seem to be getting the correct json response.

Comment: Seems to be working on my end! Glad I got the opportunity to do some web scraping with node.js, going to investigating porting my python skills to this.

Comment: That is great to hear @AaronS ! Thanks for verifying that this works :D

I will soon look into it!

Comment: How'd you get on ?

Comment: I'm workin on it now, copying your code worked perfectly fine :D, Now I'm trying to figure out which data goes where. You are a legend !!!! THANKS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218099/discussion-between-loizos-vasileiou-and-aarons).